# Как запустить обучение нейросети на локальном компьютере?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Использовал гугл колаб для обучения нейросети. Периодически вводил капчи, чтобы не выключилось обучение. Высветилось сообщение- нельзя использовать GPU Google. В итоге на 2,5 часа работы насмарку. Подскажите, как на моем локальном компе запустить обучение на GPU. С линуксом возиться не хочется.

Comment: А у вас видюха `Nvidia`, мощная? Иначе нет смысла на `GPU` учить )  Линукс не нужен, ставите `Anaconda`, например, ну и что там ещё поверх неё - `tensorflow`, `keras`, драйвера `CUDA` не забыть. И учите что хотите.

Comment: Видюха Радеон RX580. Требуется именно последовательность действий как для чайника. И что значит- нет смысла учить?

Comment: То и значит, что от хилой видюхи с небольшой памятью толку будет не больше, чем при обучении на процессоре. С радеоном всё плохо было несколько я помню, но может что и поменялось. Обычно все библиотеки для обучения на GPU поддерживают только CUDA

Comment: Хотя нет, вру. Если памяти хватает, то почти любая видюха будет быстрее, чем CPU. Но с радеоном придётся повозиться и вряд ли что получится на винде.

Comment: С радеоном и нвидией не прошло- у одной нет куды,  другая слишком простая, чтобы поддерживать её. Пробовали сделать так https://research.google.com/colaboratory/intl/ru/local-runtimes.html. Но выдаёт ошибку на стадии шаг 3. ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: Не найден указанный модуль. Не сталкивались с таким?

Comment: Какая именно dll не грузится? )  Так слишком абстрактно

Comment: Не помню уже, какая(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поставить плед, который позволил мне даже на старой AMD карте обучать https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml
А далее в коде типа такого:

```
import os

os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"    

from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Dense, BatchNormalization, Convolution1D, Convolution2D, MaxPooling1D, MaxPooling2D, RepeatVector, Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, LeakyReLU, Conv1D, LSTM, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,  ConvLSTM2D
from keras import utils
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau, CSVLogger
from keras import regularizers
from keras.models import save_model, load_model, model_from_json
```

Comment: С ним помнится тоже какие-то сложности были. Но если работает, то и хорошо.